# How to get and read specific data from XML in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

Hi everyone I have this XML structure and I would like to get the value of the `IdDocumento` attributes

```
<pago10:Pagos>
    <pago10:Pago>
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FBA" />
    </pago10:Pago>
    <pago10:Pago>
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FBA" />
        <pago10:DoctoRelacionado IdDocumento="842b32ce-44c1-4b31-96b8-3a34569c698c" />
    </pago10:Pago>
</pago10:Pagos>
```

I have tried with this as follow:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('complemento.xml');

$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('p', $ns['pago10']);


if ($xml->xpath('//p:Pagos')) {

    foreach ($xml->xpath('//p:Pagos') as $pagos10) {

        foreach ($xml->xpath('//p:Pago') as $pago10) {

            foreach ($xml->xpath('//p:DoctoRelacionado') as $doc) {

                echo $doc['IdDocumento'] . '<br>';
            }

            echo "=========================================";
        }
    }
}
```

But this is displaying the 3 attributes `IdDocumento` at once I was hoping to print the first
attribute `IdDocumento` and make the separator and then print the other two, how can I know which
IdDocumento belongs to every `pago10:Pago` node?

Expected result:

`B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FB`
`====================================`
`B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FBA`
`842b32ce-44c1-4b31-96b8-3a34569c698c`

What I'm getting:

`B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FB`
`B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FBA`
`842b32ce-44c1-4b31-96b8-3a34569c698c`
`====================================`
`B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FB`
`B670AD5D-8BA6-42CF-A0D0-1A403E042FBA`
`842b32ce-44c1-4b31-96b8-3a34569c698c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems was the way you were always using `$xml` as the start point for the XPath, so this was always going back to the top level of the document to find the next layer of elements.  In this code it uses the element from the previous `foreach()` as the start point.

Also note that it uses the descendant axis (`'descendant::`) so that this only uses elements which are under the start point.

```
$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);

$xml->registerXPathNamespace('pago10', $ns['pago10']);

if ($xml->xpath('//pago10:Pagos')) {
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//pago10:Pagos') as $pagos10) {
        foreach ($pagos10->xpath('descendant::pago10:Pago') as $pago10) {
            foreach ($pago10->xpath('descendant::pago10:DoctoRelacionado') as $doc) {

                echo $doc['IdDocumento'] . '<br>';
            }

            echo "=========================================".PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much, I didn't know about `descendant::` to find elements under.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your `xpath` in that `$xml->xpath('//p:DoctoRelacionado')` will get **all** items with `DoctoRelacionado`, not just the ones inside the current `Pago`.

Instead, only the first `foreach` should use xpath and the others should use something like the `children()` method of `SimpleXMLElement`.

To fix this, try switching your `foreach` statements for the below:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//p:Pagos') as $pagos10) {
    foreach ($pagos10->children() as $pago10) {
        foreach ($pago10->children() as $doc) {
            echo $doc['IdDocumento'] . '<br>';
        }
        echo "=========================================<br>";
    }
}
```